# sonic wall - bridge 2 lans

Tags: cisco, sonicwall

I'm trying to bridge 2 networks

- one using SonicWall NSA240 (192.168.100.1)
- one using Cisco 1940 (192.168.129.1)

Both are working as DHCP servers on their networks.
I want to access machines on the 129-network from the 100-network

I plugged the 129-network into X4 on the Sonic Wall.

X4 interface is configured with a static IP (192.168.129.29) and I added a route:

`source: X0 subnet (lan)
destination: X4 subnet (192.168.129.0/255.255.255.0)
service: any
gateway: what should I use here? 192.168.129.1 (which is the cisco address)?
interface: X3`

It doesn't work, I can't ping any 129 adresses from the 100-network. What did I miss?

Comment: I don't think you really want to bridge two networks with different addresses. You probably want to route between them. Routers get routes in three ways: directly connected, statically configured, or through a routing protocol. Don't configure gateways on routers which are routing; the routers are the gateways.

Comment: yes that's probably what I meant

Comment: Since you have resolved the problem, please post an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: RESOLVED: just had to change Link speed from Auto Negotiate to 100 Mbps - Full Duplex @RonMaupin

Comment: Right, you resolved it, but please put it in as an answer, and accept the answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to add a route on the Sonicwall, as it already has a connected route when you give it an ip address in that subnet. (Edit: well maybe you do, I have no idea how a Sonicwall works but generically speaking if it acts as a router, you shouldn't).

What you do need is to make sure that the 192.168.129.x network can reach the 192.168.100.x network. So you should either:

- add a static route on each host in 192.168.129.x, for 192.168.100.0/24 with 192.168.129.29 as next-hop
- add a static route on the cisco, for 192.168.100.0/24 with 192.168.129.29 as next-hop
- reconfigure your dhcp to give out 192.168.129.29 as default gateway (but then obviously all Internet access will go through the Sonicwall as well so you no longer use the Cisco).

Edit: And as Ron pointed out, you mis-used the term 'bridging', you connected the 2 LANs using a firewall/router, so you are routing between them, you'r not bridging them.

Comment: Thank you, @hertitu. I do understand that it should be so. I think I'm having a sonicwall related issue. Although I gave it a fixed IP (192.168.129.29), I can't ping it from the 129-network. I'm also new to SonicWall, I'm gonna do some research...

Comment: RESOLVED: just had to change Link speed from `Auto Negotiate` to `100 Mbps - Full Duplex`